# Perforce doesn't know that I have changes to submit

Tags: version-control, perforce

I'm new to Perforce. I'm much more comfortable with Git and some Subversion.

Anyway, this is what happened:

1. I created a branch for myself in p4v located in location A on my machine.
2. I created a Java project in location B, and
   **copied it** into location A on my computer.
3. I created and submitted a changelist for the Java project.
4. I realized that I needed to make another change, so I went back to Eclipse and edited the project. But, I forgot that the project in Eclipse is pointing to the one in location B.
5. So, I copied the project from location B to location A, where the branch is.

But now I can't create a changelist for the edits because Perforce thinks that there are no changes to commit.

What did I do wrong, how do I fix it, and what are some Perforce best practices to avoid this craziness in the future?

Comment: Its well worth learning how to use perforce, before doing too much with it.  Its a complex and powerful piece of software which will drive you nuts if you don't understand the concepts.  Chief among these is that it requires you tell the server when you wish to edit a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [Eclipse plugin for Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/eclipse_plugin). If you install this then you will be able work with the project in Eclipse at location A.

If you make an edit to any file or setting Perforce will check the file out automatically and place it in the default changelist.

You can then either check it back in from there or use P4V to manage your changelists.

As [@jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541249/perforce-doesnt-know-that-i-have-changes-to-submit/7541493#7541493) points out Perforce effectively "owns" the files and you shouldn't make any edits without "asking permission" first by either an explicit `p4 edit` command or via the IDE plugin.

If you've made a change *without* first checking out the file you can simply make the `p4 edit` call. This doesn't overwrite the local file, just marks the file as writeable as far as Perforce is concerned. Perforce **should** then recognise that there's an edit pending and let you check it in.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do `p4 edit` on the files before you edit them.  Normally files are marked as read-only to strongly discourage you from modifying the files without first marking them for edit.

The best practice would be not to fight the read-only permissions.

Comment: So, the weird thing is that I was able to overwrite the files w/ the copy on step 5. How come that worked? And what does that mean to Perforce?

Comment: Even if I mark those files for edit, I have no changes to make at this point. So, do I checkout those files for edit, make a change to each of them (like deleting a line), submit the changes, then check them out to undo the change in order to submit the correct version of the files? Because -- and, it might not be clear in my original question, I apologize --- Perforce, at this point, thinks that what's in my workspace is the most up-to-date version of those files, but that doesn't match what's in the depot. That's the strange thing.

Comment: From this point, if you do `p4 edit` on the modified files, that should be sufficient.  What do you mean that "Perforce thinks that what's in your workspace is the most up-to-date version"?  `p4 change` should always list all files opened for edit with `p4 edit`, regardless of whether they contain any actual modifications. (You are allowed to submit changesets with no modifications.) If you do `p4 diff` on the files, does it show no change?